# Exclude results for a given year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to exclude `Jerry` from `2019` (orderyear) and only show sales for him in 2018. What can I add to my code to remove Jerry's 2019 sales. I am using SSMS 2016.

```
select orderyear, case when code = '2099' then 'Laura'
                       when code = '3099' then 'John'
                       when code = '4099' then 'Jerry'
                  end as 'Members', count(sales)numberofsales
from mytable
group by orderyear, case when code = '2099' then 'Laura'
                         when code = '3099' then 'John'
                         when code = '4099' then 'Tony'
                    end
```

Results:

```
orderyear            members                numberofsales
  2018                John                       200
  2019                John                       100
  2018                Laura                      300
  2019                Laura                      350
  2018                Jerry                      400
  2019                Jerry                      450
```

Requested:

```
orderyear            members                numberofsales
  2018                John                       200
  2019                John                       100
  2018                Laura                      300
  2019                Laura                      350
  2018                Jerry                      400
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
where not (code = '4099' and orderyear = 2019)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify to this:

```
select 
  orderyear, 
  case code 
    when '2099' then 'Laura'
    when '3099' then 'John'
    when '4099' then 'Jerry'
  end as Members, 
  count(sales) numberofsales
from mytable
where
  orderyear <> 2019 or code <> '4099'
group by 
  orderyear, 
  code
```